# Ошибка в установке mysqlclient на хостинге через ssh (django,python 3.7.3)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django

**Друзья, подскажите почему mysqlclient не хочет устанавливаться?**
ход действий был как [указано на сайте по ссылке](https://hoster.by/help/unix-khosting-nastroyka/ustanovka-django/)

Если в кратце:

- создал приложение Python на хостинге в cpanel
- создал БД
- зашёл через SSH в виртуальное окружение
- получил ошибку после этой команды pip install django mysqlclient

---

```
   (mysite:3.7)[u91715@whm5 mysite]$ pip install django mysqlclient
Requirement already satisfied: django in /home/u91715/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.0.5)
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /home/u91715/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django) (2019.3)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref~=3.2 in /home/u91715/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django) (3.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in /home/u91715/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django) (0.3.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/u91715/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f3hrb87f/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f3hrb87f/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-0g98v_yc
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-f3hrb87f/mysqlclient/
  Complete output (35 lines):
  /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
  /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
  /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
  /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  MySQLdb/_mysql.c:29:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
   #include "mysql.h"
                     ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/u91715/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f3hrb87f/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f3hrb87f/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-gzjcm687/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/u91715/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-f3hrb87f/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (35 lines):
    /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
    /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
    /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
    /bin/mysql_config: line 8: rpm: command not found
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:29:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
     #include "mysql.h"
                       ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/u91715/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/bin/python3.7_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f3hrb87f/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f3hrb87f/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-gzjcm687/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/u91715/virtualenv/mysite/3.7/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

В той ссылке же все написано

Вариант для тарифов с поддержкой компилятора: pip install django mysqlclient
Вариант для остальных тарифов: pip install django pymysql
То есть для работы с базой данных можно использовать разные библиотеки. По умолчанию, работа Django предполагается с компилируемым модулем mysqlclient. Вариант с pymysql не требует наличия компилятора, но нужны будут правки в коде запуска приложения и установленных, которые рассмотрим ниже.
Тариф видео без поддержки компилятора
Пробуйте через pymysql
Ну или пишите в тех поддержку